# Android First App unable to create

Tags: android

"problem in creating first android application without any error"

I am new to android application...  I have already installed eclipse Juno and used it to run simple java programs. Then I downloaded Android SDK bundled with ADT, which has eclipse attached with it. Therefore, when I opened newly installed Eclipse ...

I found my old files made in existing IDE also accessed via new eclipse IDE....  and new-- > android app option was too showing

To resolve 2 IDE issue,  I deleted old existing IDE in My laptop and using Bundled eclipse,  created a new android application ..

But on clicking finish button when i was naming the file: the first step that is now not creating any package or application ..

and not showing any error message..

"I have searched across Google found application creation problems are with error messages...."

but in my case No error message is shown .. still unable to create ...

Not getting what is the problem here..
please help me to find the problem thanks...

Comment: Please: 1) Use punctuation as this is nearly impossible to read. 2) Ask a question. 3) Make it understandable to others. 4) Be specific about what is and what is not happening and what your problem is.

Comment: I have edited question apologise for inconvience..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new workspace (only for Android apps) from the File menu.
2. After Eclipse restarts in the newly created workspace, create your File->New->Android app project.

If  the above two steps do not work for you, please post if you have Android SDK installed and Eclipse->Preferences->Android is pointing at the right location.

Comment: Now when I am Clicking to run the android application foloowing messages are showing in console..